# Updated IntelliJ, can't find shelf?

Tags: intellij-idea

I updated my IntelliJ to 2021.3.3, now I can no longer find my shelf tab. It's no longer showing up on the Git tab, and I don't see it under View > Tool Windows. I previously had stuff in it I now need to unshelve. Where has it gone?

Comment: Git > Uncommitted Changes > Show Shelf?

Comment: Thanks, I see it there. Not sure why the tab was removed, but using those menu options brought it back. Happy to accept your answer if posted as an answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the shelf in **Git > Uncommitted Changes > Show Shelf**. From then on it should show up as a tab in the commit tool window as well.